# Autolayout constraints set in code not appearing in interface builder

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a custom view that is set in interface builder with top, leading, trailing, height constraints.

In my Custom view i have a title and a button.
Im trying to add to the title a bottom and centerY constraints.
and to the button width, height, bottom, leading constraints.

When i add any constraint i get an warning in interface builder:

> Expected: width=600, height=68.
>
> Actual: width=0, height=0

When i run the code everything works, but i cant see anything in interface builder.

code:

```
@IBDesignable
class UIHeader: UIView {

var delegate: HeaderDelegate?

private lazy var titleLable: UILabel = {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lbl.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Light", size: 16)
    lbl.text = "Title"
    return lbl
}()

private lazy var backButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let image = UIImage(named: "prev")
    if let image = image {
        btn.setImage(image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
    }
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UIHeader.OnBackButtonClickLister(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return btn
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}
}

extension UIHeader {

@IBInspectable
var backButtonImage: UIImage? {
    get {
        return backButton.imageForState(.Normal)
    }
    set (newImage) {
        backButton.setImage(newImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var title: String? {
    get {
        return titleLable.text
    }
    set (newTitle) {
        titleLable.text = newTitle
    }
}
}

extension UIHeader {
private func setupView() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(titleLable)
    addSubview(backButton)
    
    //add shadow
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 115/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowRadius = 8
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        //Title//
        //center x
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLable, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        //bottom
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: titleLable, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 12),
        
        //button//
        //bottom
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: backButton, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 4),
        
        //leading
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: backButton, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        
        //width
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: backButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 40),
        
        //height
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: backButton, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
        ])
}
}
```

I also tried to add the constraints with:

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint)
```

cant figure out what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is you're trying to do this in `init` before layout has occurred.

Comment: @Michael, what do you mean? where am i doing this?

Comment: Your `init` calls `setupView()` to create new constraints which are dependent on existing UI attributes that haven't been set yet because layout hasn't occurred. I'm just suspecting this is the source of the warning. You could try making the call in `layoutSubviews` instead to see if the warning goes away.

Comment: Im using the tutorial from
 https://www.raywenderlich.com/117757/video-tutorial-introducing-custom-controls-part-1-your-first-custom-control, but i will try it out and see what happens, thanks

Comment: I'd trust them over my theories any day. I don't subscribe so I can't see that one - how old is it? Maybe it could be out of date?

Comment: September 1, 2015, the only difference between are code is that there using ios9  ancher constraints and i'm using ios8 NSLayoutConstraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed

```
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

and everything works great.